# Does the SimpleRNN in Keras have a hidden state, or does it just use the output value as the hidden state?

Tags: keras, rnn

When using `tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN`,does this SimpleRNN have a hidden state, or does it just use the output value as the hidden state. That is, does it follow the formulas $h_t = \tanh(w_h\cdot h_{t-1} + w_x\cdot  x_{t-1}+b_h)$, $y_t = w_o\cdot h_t + b_o$? Or is $h_t=y_t$?

If the input is of length 5, and I make `keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1)`, why are there only 6 parameters according to the summary. There should be 5 for $w_x$, 1 for $b_h$, 1 for $w_h$, and possibly 2 for output, for a total to 7 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

Note: In `Keras`, every `SimpleRNN` has only three different weight matrices, and these weights are shared between all input cells;
In other words, for all five cells in your network:
\begin{align}
h_t = tanh( w_{h} h_{t-1}  + w_{x} x_{t} + b_h)\ ; t= 1..5
\end{align}
For a deeper understanding of recurrent networks in `Keras`, you may want to read this eloquent article: [Mohit Mayank - A practical guide to RNN and LSTM in Keras](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-practical-guide-to-rnn-and-lstm-in-keras-980f176271bc).

Answer (score 0):

From my experience and from [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-practical-guide-to-rnn-and-lstm-in-keras-980f176271bc) it appears that `SimpleRNN` simply uses the hidden state as output. It does not compute any separate output. This is not stated explicitly in the official documentation.

Using the code below you can see it for yourself that the state and output are always the same.

```py
inputs = np.random.random([2, 3, 1]).astype(np.float32)
simple_rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(4, return_state=True)

output, state = simple_rnn(inputs)

print(output)
print("====")
print(state)
```